# css float issue when adding dynamically div

Tags: html, css

I have a design as following line:

[image]

When I add a new div after any block (1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th), it breaks the div which is positioned below it.

When I add div after 1st div, design takes the following:

[image]

CSS rules of divs is just:

```
width: 430px; margin-bottom:40px; float:left(for 1st and 3rd) or right(for 2nd and 4th)
```

CSS rules of div which is appended:

```
height:20px; width:20px; clear:both; overflow:hidden
```

What causes this problem?

Why bottom div positioning on right instead of slide down?

Comment: clear:both; and you ask why it is breaking the float?

Comment: @axel A reverse engg of your comment will lead him to answer.

Comment: Maybe on the second image there should be one div more, but it may doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Shail yes, it is part of it, but there can be more problems, what about the floating, if he is using nth-child, this is getting funny. So no satisfying answer before some real CSS / HTML code or a fiddle.

Comment: Please post the code or create a test page ...  IMages wont help much. Its not a image riddle .. so to get programming help you need to paste Code code code and more code .... Read the guidelines Pleaseeeeeeee

Comment: Hey did you solve this or you need help? If you add your code downvoters will change their decision. Be courageous! (Or let us know if it is solved.)

Comment: clear:both; solved my problem. When I add clear:both; property before asking here, it wasn't worked. Because there were points that I missed. After @axel's comment, I thought about it again. Then, I saw that I have to add this property to divs only positioned on left side. After this solution, an another problem occured.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use tables and your problem will be easily done.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
  .div
        {
            width: 400px;
            margin: 20px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        .divwrapper
        {
            width: 900px;
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divwrapper">
        <div class="div">
            Hello 1Div
        </div>
        <div class="div">
            Hello 2Div
        </div>
        <div class="div">
            Hello 3Div
        </div>
        <div class="div">
            Hello 4Div
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write css for all div like

```
div{
   width:80px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  height:50px;
}
```

but, i think css solution not give by simple text. so

please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pvnq8/1/